# AWS Athena - outerjoin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have 2 tables. In one of the tables a few rows are missing. If I need to include all the rows in table 1 including that are missing in table 2, what's the query?
I tried similar queries:
SELECT customer.name, orders.price
FROM customer LEFT OUTER JOIN orders
ON customer.id = orders.customer_id

Please check the attachments for the output of the query:

Comment: the attachment is missing.

Comment: Please share sample data and desired output.